# How to get a CSS animation to run through the correct steps

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have this code in CSS:

```
@keyframes blink
{
    0% { background: #000000; }
    100% { background: #b22222; }
}

.alert
{
    animation: blink 2s steps(2) infinite;
}
```

I have created to frames at 0% and at 100% and I set up the animation to have two steps, to make the background blink from black to a bright redish.

I would think the two steps when playing the animation would be 0% and 100%, but it seems like it plays the two steps as 0% and 50%. Because I don't get a bright redish, but more a mix between the 0% frame and the 100% frame.

How can I make this animation play the two steps correctly, one step at 0% and one at 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To it work you should change two things:

- Change `animation-timing-function` to `step(1)` - so your animation has only one step (50%) besides the initial state (0%).
- Change `100%` to `50%` - because you want the color to change at the middle of the animation duration.

And it will works:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes blink
{
    0% { background: #000000; }
    50% { background: #b22222; }
}

.alert
{
    -webkit-animation: blink 2s steps(1) infinite;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">Hello</span>
```

ps.: I changed to -webkit- so I could run it here...